# How to insert variable from NodeJs into a python script?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, serial-port

I am using `python-shell` to run my python script within my NodeJs environment.

I have the following NodeJs code:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var command = 'open1';
var comport = 6;

var options = {
    scriptPath: 'python/scripts'
};

PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

and I need to be able to include the command and COMPORT variable into the python `controlLock` script before the script gets executed (otherwise it wont have the right value).

Below is the `controlLock.py` file

```
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program MUST be at same rate 
ser.port = "COM{}".format(comport) 
ser.timeout = 10 
ser.open() 
#call the serial_connection() function 
ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [run the python script with arguments](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell#running-a-python-script-with-arguments-and-options). The `options` that you pass to `PythonShell.run()` has a property called `args` that you can use to pass arguments to the python script. You can then [read these command line arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) from the python script and insert where they are needed.

***`python-shell` arguments***

```
var options = {
  scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
  args: [command, comport], // pass arguments to the script here
};
```

***python script***

```
# 0 is the script itself, technically an argument to python
script = sys.argv[0]

# 1 is the command arg you passed
command = sys.argv[1]

# 2 is the comport arg you passed
comport = sys.argv[2]
```